# Отступ (абзац) после приветствия

Tags: общие-вопросы, оформление-текста, абзац

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужен ли отступ (абзац) после приветствия в данном случае?

*Здравствуйте!*

[отступ]

*Меня зовут Ирина, мне 16 лет...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все варианты — и с отступом, и без него — возможны. Более того, вы можете не отделять приветствие вовсе и писать всё в одну строчку с основным текстом письма.

Здесь нет никаких конкретных правил, но есть личные традиции: например, я всегда выделяю приветствие в отдельный абзац. Среди моих собеседников есть и те, кто пишут так: "Привет, *имя*! Ты давно не писал, я уже начал волноваться..."